# Form authentication timout is bigger then session timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am implementing site with login via facebook.
I call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(response.email, true); after facebook authenticates user.

Form authentication timeout is set to 129600 (3 month).

Should i set session timeout to the same value?
As far as I understand session timeout should be as few as possible.

Is it normal if session timeout less then form timeout? (for example form 129600 session 30)

I know that there are many similar questions, but this problem isn't clear for me.

Thanks.

Comment: it can't be simpler than this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178176/differences-in-forms-auth-timeout-and-session-timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using cookies for authentication, your server session doesn't matter. A potential problem is that if you store data on `Session` object and it expires, that could cause troubles to user since functionality depending on this data would probably fail.

If you handle server `Session` expiration properly, you won't have any problem.