# "Remember Me" not working on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, session, cookies

I'm implementing "Remember Me" feature, I want the user to not have to enter login/password again.

It's seems to work in local, but in a shared hosting, It last for about 15 minutes then logout. Here is the code:

**controller**:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", true);
```

**Web.config**:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="262974" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="262974" cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

**EDIT**

I've added the sessionState, but still the same problem, working on local and **not on the server**?

what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution, I had to use `StateServer` instead of `InProc` and also a machine key, Here is the full solution:

**Controller:**

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", true);
```

**Web.config:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="262974" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>

<sessionState mode="StateServer" timeout="262974" cookieless="UseCookies" />

<machineKey validationKey="5BAE63F50C69C1BBB7BFC2E696674389C307E28E9DEB60FB273B85CAD8FC3C2261FB13DF92B90A99C6EB684FDB1F6E3E92E1A42083EB77B5918126DD52245FB5" decryptionKey="11F6FE0C790413FFF3E230387168016B212216DEF727C4157CDDD0558BEAE5B7" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

I have a shared hosting with *Arvixe* and it's in their Support where I found the solution: [support.arvixe.com](https://support.arvixe.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/143/11/aspnet-session-state)

Answer (score 4):

Look into the [sessionstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.100).aspx) element in your web.config. For example:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" />
```

Check out the following SO question for differences between the [sessionstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.100).aspx) element and the [forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) element in your web.config:
[Differences in forms auth timeout and session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178176/differences-in-forms-auth-timeout-and-session-timeout)

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2178224/444610) by [@womp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63756/womp) states the following:

> A session starts every time a new user hits the website, regardless of
>   whether or not they are anonymous. Authentication has very little to
>   do with Session.
>
> Authentication timeout is the amount of time that the authentication
>   cookie is good for on the user's browser. Once the cookie expires,
>   they must re-authenticate to access protected resources on the site.
>
> So, if Session times out before the Authentication cookie - they are
>   still authenticated, but all their session variables disappear, and
>   may cause errors in your website if you are not disciplined in
>   checking for nulls and other conditions brought about by missing
>   session.
>
> If Authentication times out before the session, then all their session
>   variables will still exist, but they won't be able to access protected
>   resources until they log back in again.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I didn't have this line in my Web.config, I'm testing it now !

Comment: That's not working either, It must be the server's configuration, cause in local, it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Go to : ASP.NET Settings  and scroll to Session settings change "value" none to "Forms" It will be done!
[image: Go to Authentication modo]