# MVC ASP.NET website logging out earlier than settings show

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I have the following config in an attempt to allow the session to be retained for around 239 minutes, however the session is lost in less than an hour.

```
<system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="240" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
       ...
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="239" />
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
       ...
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

I don't believe there to be any C# code overriding these settings.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: When you use InProc on the session, is very possible to lose it earlier. Try to move it to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you also have an *idle time-out* setting on the application pool process which is set to 20 minutes by default, e.g. every 20 minutes (if no activity) the app pool is reset which also would throw away any active in-proc sessions.

[image]

Comment: IIS setting changed and tested OK - spot on thanks perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

The way that session timeouts and forms authentication timeouts work completely different.

- [Differences in forms auth timeout and session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178176/differences-in-forms-auth-timeout-and-session-timeout)
- [Forms Authentication Timeout vs Session Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470777/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-session-timeout)
- http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/12/caution-with-using-sessiontimeout-and.html