# ASP .Net timeout not working / IIS

Tags: asp.net, timeout, iis-7.5

I already tried:

```
•Application Pool => Advanced Settings => Process Model => Idle Time-out(minutes) = 0

•Sites => ASP => Session Properties => Time-out = 720 minutes

•Sites => Configuration Editor => system.web/sessionState => timeout = 720 minutes

•Sites => Configuration Editor => system.web/roleManager => cookieTimeout = 720 minutes
```

In `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="720" />
</authentication>

<roleManager cookieTimeout="720" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">

<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="720">
```

Also tried to put recycling (regular time) to 0.

Still, after 1 hour more ou less the session goes down.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Very strange, after 1 hour the w3wp.exe process has the same id? Have you tryed to check the cookie with a proxy (for example fiddler) to check the expire time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session or Forms auth expires?  They are two different timeouts that do not behave the same.  You can loos your `Session` when you run out of memory.

[Differences in forms auth timeout and session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178176/differences-in-forms-auth-timeout-and-session-timeout?rq=1)

Comment: A found a code:

var authenticationTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(viewModel.Login, false, 720);

It was 60 minutes, now I put 720. But this still not work. After 1 hour it returns to my login page. I looked the iis server and all properties seens to be ok, just like I set in my application. Any idea?